# Getting a value from a datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

So ive read quite a lot of info on how to get a value out from a datagrid. Heres the datagrid ive created.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="257" HorizontalAlignment="Left"              Margin="12,41,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" IsReadOnly="True"    CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Opgave" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Udvikler" Binding="{Binding Creator}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And what i want to is to get the value from the first cell in the selected row (The id)

This is what ive come up with.

```
            string i = dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0].Value;
```

Problem is that many people are using this tip but somehow it does not understand the keyword value. Am i missing something or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather use the bound object than getting values based on the grid. You can get the object bound to the selected row rather easy.

```
var selectedObject = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as YourClass;
var id = selectedObject.Id;
```

Just replace `YourClass` with the Type of object you bound to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

[`DataGrid.SelectedCells[0]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells.aspx) returns a [DataGridCellInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcellinfo.aspx). Use

```
var i = (dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0].Item as YourClass).Id
```

Comment: Tried that now but it just said i was null